# Parametrically Defined Curves: $f'$ and $g'$ Are Not Simultaneously Zero

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, derivatives, curves, parametrization

I can't find a clear, comprehensive explanation, on this site or elsewhere, for why parametrically defined curves frequently have the condition that the the derivatives of their points $x = f(t)$ and $y = g(t)$ cannot simultaneously be zero on the interval $[a, b]$.

Most of the explanations use language that assumes that the reader already understands the concept they're explaining, or the explanations make the meaningless claim that the curve must be "nice".

I would appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain, comprehensively (not rigorously), what is meant by this condition. If you're going to use words that are likely to be unfamiliar to someone who doesn't understand this concept, like "regular", then please take the time to define what it means.

Comment: It means the curve has a non zero speed for each value of the parameter. This means that the curve in an injective map so that any point on the curve defines a unique value of the parameter.

Comment: @copper.hat So for example $t\mapsto(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ is injective? Ok, you meant locally injective. But I really don't think this is exactly the point - the "bad" parametrization of the curve $y=|x|$ in my  answer is injective...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I meant locally, it was more of a comment than a complete answer.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I guess I would settle for rectifiable, but as your answer nicely demonstrates, this allows a lot of curves that don't fit with our intuition.

Comment: @copper.hat In fact I'm pretty sure that any rectifiable curve has a $C^1$ parametrization...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Do you have a pointer for that please? I can see Lipschitz, but am curious how the reparametrisation would be done on the null set.

Comment: @copper.hat Thinking about it I'm really  not so sure. The idea, which may or may not work, is to slow down to zero velocity at every point where the curve is not differentiable, as in the answer I gave. Say $\gamma(t)$ is Lipschitz and $E$ is the set of $t$ where $\gamma$ is not differentiable. I believe I can do this if $E$ happens to be compact. In fact $E$ _is_ an $F_\sigma$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: That is where I get stuck...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: To be frank, I have been stuck on this part for a few decades now, starting with an early course in complex analysis where the instructor did not distinguish parameterised curves from their ranges. I dream of being a real mathematician...

Comment: The curve may intersect itself, hence it is not necessarily injective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is we want to say a curve is smooth, for example $C^1$ (continuously differentiable), if it has a smooth parametrization. And without that condition on non-vanishing derivatives that would admit "smooth" curves that we really don't want to call "smooth".

**Example:** Consider the curve in the plane defined by $y=|x|$. That has a corner at the origin - our definition of "$C^1$ curve" had better not include this curve, right?

But define $f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ by $g(t)=t^2$ and $$f(t)=\begin{cases}
t^2,&(t\ge0),
\\-t^2,&(t<0).\end{cases}$$Then $f$ and $g$ are both $C^1$, and $x=f(t)$, $y=g(t)$ is a parametrization of the curve $y=|x|$. Without the condition on non-vanishing derivatives this would make $y=|x|$ a $C^1$ curve. (With the condition on non-vanishing derivatives everything's fine - this parametization is disallowed because $f'(0)=g'(0)=0$.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. So what is the connection between this and the condition that the derivatives of the points of the curve cannot simultaneously be zero? For instance, you used the curve $y=|x|$ as an example, but this doesn't have derivatives equal to $0$ at any point; rather, it is only undefined at $x = 0$, since this is a corner. Furthermore, I don't see any reference at all to the concept that my question referenced, which is the points being simultaneously being zero. [...]

Comment: Again, I appreciate the answer, but this was written *by* someone who understands the concept, *for* someone who understands the concept. I cannot derive anything useful from this, despite putting in the effort to understand it.

Comment: @ThePointer The point is that although the curve $y=|x|$ is not differentiable, the paramteriization $(x(t),y(t))$ that I gave _is_ differentiable! So we need to not allow that parametrization. If add the condition about non-vanishing derivatives we rule out that parametrization, since $x'(0)=y'(0)=0$.

Comment: @ThePointer: The point here is that the curve is continuously differentiable everywhere, but it has a kink when you just look at the range of the curve. Our natural inclination is to consider such curves as not being smooth even though they are.

Comment: @copper.hat As I'm sure you understand, just to prevent any possible confuusion: The _parametrization_ is differentiable. The curve is _not_  differentiable - that's the point to the technicality in the definition of "differentiable curve".

Comment: @ThePointer: The functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ in this answer are what you call $f(t)$ and $g(t)$. They are both differentiable and have derivatives equal to $0$ at $t=0$.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for that! I hadn't noticed his "$f$" and "$g$"...

Comment: @ThePointer I hadn't noticed the notation you were using. Answer revised to make the notation more consistent with the notation in the question.

Comment: I've studied your answer and I think I understand now. So are you saying that it can be proven that all curves $C$ that aren't smooth will have some point $c \in [a, b]$ in their parameterisations $x = f(t)$, $y = g(t)$ such that $f'(c) = g'(c) = 0$? And, since we want to avoid curves that aren't smooth, we therefore also want to avoid curves that have a parameterisation where the derivatives of the coordinates are simultaneously zero?

Comment: @ThePointer Yes, more or less. I'm not quite saying what you said about _proving_ things about curves that are not smooth. Before we can prove anything like that we need to _define_ what a smooth curve is... If we make the definition the way we do then what you say about non-smooth curves  is true, just _by definition_.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Ahh, yes, because, as you said, "we want to say a curve is smooth, for example $C^1$ (continuously differentiable), if it has a smooth parametrization."

Comment: Your answer, combined with your comment in Yves Daoust's answer, clarifies it for me: "This is undesirable behavior because if we don't disallow this behavior we find the the curve $y = |x|$ is "differentiable", as I showed in my answer. We certainly don't want that - if $y = |x|$."
 is a "differentiable" curve then differentiable curves are nothing like what we think they should be."

Comment: Makes total sense now! If we didn't have this condition, then we would classify non-differentiable curves as differentiable just by parameterising them in a certain way, right? And that would compromise our definition of what it means for a curve to be or not be differentiable?

Comment: @ThePointer Right.

Answer (score 0):

Because when $f'=g'=0$, the direction of the curve is no more defined. At such a point, the curve could change direction abruptly.

[Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid).

Comment: Singular point: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingularPoint.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. So the reason for this condition is that we want the parameterised curve to be unidirectional?

Comment: @ThePointer: what do you mean by unidirectional ?

Comment: @ThePointer: "in one direction" means following a straight line. I doubt this is what you have in mind. But I have completely rephrased my answer.

Comment: So the reason for this condition is to avoid parameterisations where the direction changes abruptly?

Comment: @ThePointer: I'd prefer to say where the direction is undefined.

Comment: Hmm, so why is this undesirable behaviour? Let's say the direction is undefined: so what? What are the consequences for a parameterised curve that exhibits this behaviour?

Comment: @ThePointer: because the direction of the curve is an essential property in many problems.

Comment: @ThePointer This is undesirable behavior because if we don't disallow this behavior we find the the curve $y=|x|$ is "differentiable", as I showed in my answer. We certainly don't want that - if  $y=|x|$ is a "differentiable" curve then differentiable curves are nothing like what we think they should be.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, I think I understand now. See my comment on your answer.